# Find memory leaks in vxworks target board

Tags: c, memory-leaks, vxworks

I am working on VxWorks target board. I want to make sure that my application or driver does not have any memory leak.

> Is there any specific way so that I can check memory leak at run time
>   or without running the application?

Comment: use `valgrind` function to check!

Comment: @sathish- thanks. Unfortunately, I am using Windows and "valgrind" is not yet available for Windows. Even if I get Linux machine, I need to run my code in Linux.however, my target board is VxWorks.So, it would be better to run the code in target board and get sort of watcher installed on target board which keeps track of memory leaks.

Comment: More to the point, valgrind doesnt support vxworks

Answer (score 2):

You need [MemScope](http://www.windriver.com/cgi-bin/partnerships/directory/viewProd.cgi?id=990) provided by Wind River which is compatible with vxworks also refer http://borkhuis.home.xs4all.nl/vxworks/vxw_pt6.html#6.2

Answer (score 1):

Although it is inaccurate you can use the `memShow` command on the VxWorks shell.

To check for memory leaks do a "base line" after your application has started. Then run your tests or stimulate your application or simply let it run for a few hours. After that check the outputs of `memShow` again. If the values have changed "dramatically" you have a problem.

Notes:

- This is very basic and just helps you to know that you actually have a memory leak. It does not show you which thread, or function...
- Remeber that this function shows the total available memory (not only to your application). So some changes are normal due to VxWorks operating...